# Error: Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnyRes

Tags: androidx

在升级androidX包后遇到的问题 编译通过 运行是报错 错误如下

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnyRes","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58.jar, /home/gx/Documents/AndroidDeveloperProjects/AndroidModuler/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/61.jar
>     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>     Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnyRes

Answer (score 0):

删除 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true 即可